# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.CodeAnalysis

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a webproject I am trying to host, but when the server tries to compile it, I get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CommandLine.Program.Main(String[] args)

So the server has an older version of CodeAnalysis than my project. So lets try a binding redirect!

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.9.9.9" newVersion="1.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Sadly, I still get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Similar issue with solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40235284/asp-net-mvc-razor-view-cs1525-invalid-expression-term

Comment: In my case, it was wrong DLL versions specified in my config's: `<system.codedom><compilers>`.

Comment: same problem
i installed version 2.0.1
and copied part of web.config from different project that has 2.0.0 in it downgraded the install to 2.0.0 and it works ok now ill upgrade back to 2.0.1 after check that all is working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, version= 1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependenc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536506/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-codeanalysis-version-1-3-1-0-cultu)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I figured this out myself. To anyone reading this, the problem was that the Nuget package `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` (which also contains the CodeAnalysis package) was the wrong version. I created a new webproject, updated the offending Nuget package right away, and the problem was solved.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just delete the packages folder in explorer, then right the solution in Visual Studio and click "Restore NuGet Packages".

Comment: If only you had told me that before I spend 3 hours trying to fix this error. :-)

Comment: Thank you to you both - it saved me a lot of time.

Comment: I used @FrankTzanabetis comment, but then had to delete the website folder and re-deploy.  After that, it worked.

Comment: In my case I had installed the beta version of the "Microsoft.Net.Compilers" package... why did I even do that? sigh...

Comment: Also consider manually updating the related assembly version in Web.config: `<system.codedom><compilers><compiler ... type="...Version=..." ... />...`. This wasn't updated automatically after nuget update of `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` in my case (VS 2015).

Comment: Awesome !! This saved my day!!

Comment: When I install the DotNetCompilerPlatform nuget package into my .NET5 project, I get an additional warning `warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform 3.6.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' 
instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.` - the references to .NET framework are not true, it's a pure Net5 solution

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this issue but ensuring that the version numbers of the assemblies in my web.config were correct.

**Edit:**

I hit this problem as well and some may wonder how the Web.Config can become incorrect. In my case I am using Web.Config Transforms so the Web.Config file gets overwritten:
[image]

Changing the version number in Web.Configs compiler (in the Web.Template.Config) to the number matches the NuGet version *does* solve the issue:

```
<compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.5.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Other possible fix (at least for Visual Studio 2015):

**Get the latest Visual Studio update.**

You can check for updates by going to `Tools/Extensions and Updates/Updates`

Same as this Q/A: [Visual Studio 2015: Quick Actions no longer working, error: Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.CodeAnalysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42484325/visual-studio-2015-quick-actions-no-longer-working-error-could-not-load-file?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 3):

I have had this problem today while doing an Umbraco v7.13.0 upgrade, simply updating the following package has fixed my problem, this is apparently a common problem with things like [Umbraco upgrades](https://our.umbraco.com/forum/extending-umbraco-and-using-the-api/78328-modelsbuilder-microsoftcodeanalysiscsharp-error).

```
Update-Package -Reinstall Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of mentioned options work, please go for this answer. Basically, you are registering that **Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll** to GAC

[Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, version= 1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependenc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536506/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-codeanalysis-version-1-3-1-0-cultu/44152052#44152052)

Answer (score -2):

Right click on your project >> Manage Nuget packages manager for solution >> Tap on Updates >> Update your 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform' >> and then run your project again.