# Asp.net MVC Razor view - CS1525: Invalid expression term '.'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, roslyn, c#-6.0

I have two identical ASP.Net 4.6 MVC project, project 1 is using roslyn complier within the site which is working fine.

**c:\windows\system32\inetsrv>C:\Websites1\bin\roslyn\csc.exe
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 1.2.0.60325**

With the second project I'm getting the error below, it's using the complier from .Net framework.

**c:\windows\system32\inetsrv> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe"
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.1590.0**

`Line 6:      @if (!Model?.Item?.IsDerived(Templates.PageMetadata.ID) ?? true)
Line 7:      {
Line 8:          return;`

`c:\Website2\Views\metadata.cshtml(6,17): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '.'
c:\Website2\Views\metadata.cshtml(6,18): error CS1003: Syntax error, ':' expected
c:\Website2\Views\metadata.cshtml(6,23): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '.'
c:\Website2\Views\metadata.cshtml(6,24): error CS1003: Syntax error, ':' expected
c:\Website2\Views\metadata.cshtml(6,68): error CS1002: ; expected
c:\Website2\Views\metadata.cshtml(6,68): error CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'
c:\Website2\Views\metadata.cshtml(6,69): error CS1002: ; expected`

I've used **Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform** on both project.

My question is why is the second project not using roslyn complier and is there a way to force it to use the roslyn complier within the site?

I've also tried **Microsoft.Net.Compilers** nuget package.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Got it working now after adding the following to the web.config

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

Comment: Do note there's a version number of the assembly in there. If you install 1.0.3, you have to change the `1.0.0.0` to `1.0.3.0`

Answer (score 3):

I just faced a similar issue and fixed it by doing as Huzzi suggested by adding the  tags into the main web project's web.config and making sure that you have installed 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform' from nuget.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the "Target framework" value in your application properties to a newer one.

Comment: I've tried changing it to 5.2.. Makes no difference.

Comment: I've tried different version like 4.6.1 / 5.2 no difference.