# Issue with occasionally null property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

This is an asp.net MVC project using LINQ and c#.

I'm pulling a list of records(list1) from an API.  I then have a table(table1) associated to some of these records(list1) if I have created one.  This table(table1) is for rating the records coming from the service(list1).

I can't use a calculated field on list1 because for performance reasons; I'd like to be able to store the value in table1 and just look at the most up to date rating.

Everything seems to work fine except that I can't use this field on a view because I get an object reference does not equal...  It can't handle the null value that exists sometimes.

My view looks like:

```
Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => list1.table1.Rating)%
```

My attempted model looks like:

```
public Table1 Table1 { get; set; }
```

Table1 is linked to list1 by an id.

So first - is there any way to save what I've done and just tell the view to return blank if there's no record in table1 that links to list1.

If not, how else can I store this record and have it associated with list1?

Thank you

Comment: `Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => list1?.table1?.Rating)%` could help you out?

Comment: I was excited - no red lines, but I get CS1525: Invalid expression term '.' with your suggestion JohanP

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40235284/asp-net-mvc-razor-view-cs1525-invalid-expression-term

Comment: `Html.DisplayFor` should handle the null. Are you sure that is where you are getting the null reference exception ?