# C# Array.Exists lambda expression CS1525: Invalid expression term '>'

Tags: c#, iis, ashx

have this C# code

```
string[] statuses = { "created", "paid", "pending", "authorized", "shipping", "completed", "canceled", "expired" };
string status = "pending";
if (Array.Exists(statuses, element => element == status.Trim())){
    context.Response.Write("match!");
}
```

it is inside *.ashx file. Tested on two IIS servers, on the first one it works fine, but on the second - have this error

> Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term '>'

I am newbie in .net, but looks like compiler there think that `>` is the part of lambda expression, while expression should only start after `=>`, can somebody explain to me, please, why this happens and where I am wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: You have dynamic compilation set up, where you only provide the source of the HTTP handler? Do you use same compiler version on both servers?

Comment: @GSerg unfortunately I have no access to those servers, just made ashx file and gave it to the owner, he gave me two links, one working and another - not

Comment: One solution is to precompile and give the dll with the ashx file. Another is to put something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40360029/11683) in the web.config that is alongside the ashx.

Comment: May I know whether you are deploying the handler on a legacy web server which only support c# 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid using lambda you could use this:

```
if (statuses.Contains(status.Trim()))
    context.Response.Write("match!");
```

Comment: ``statuses`` is array, so I need to do it in the loop, but idea was clear, thank you

Comment: @crangcrang array is IEnumerable. [Nothing stops you from using it with Linq .Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-objects)