# Visual Studio 2015: Quick Actions no longer working, error: Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.CodeAnalysis

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Until yesterday, I could happily use Quick Actions and Refactoring in Visual Studio 2015. Today, it no longer works, even after restarting the PC and creating a completely new solution.

Yesterday, when I changed a variable name, a light bulb appeared and I could ask VS to rename wherever this variable name was used.

Today, the light bulb does not appear. When I right click the variable name, I can select the menu Quick Actions and Refactoring, but then I get the error message: "Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, OublicKeyTaken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Any help with fixing this problem is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35791592/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-codeanalysis

Comment: @Mahdi: I saw that post before I asked my question. There it was a compilation problem and the error was "The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference", which I don't get. My VS compiles just fine. So far I only noticed a problem in the editor. I also don't know how I can apply their solution for a web project to my console application.

Comment: This has just started happening to me too.  A coincidence that you saw it only 3 days ago as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2015 Update 2.
I solved it by installing Update 3 for Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: This worked for me too.  I don't know whether it was anything in Update 2 that was the problem (why start failing now?) or that simply the act of effectively re-installing solved it.  Apparently Update 3 has been around since June 2016, but I've never been offered it automatically.  I downloaded from here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs

Comment: I even didn't know I have update 2 and there is an update 3. When I did the update, my PC crashed after an hour or so, then complained that my drive C: has a problem and I have to run chkdsk. Now my PC is running again, the Quick Actions are working again in VS (thanks @xerdan), but I wonder what got spoiled by the crashing upgrade. Worst case, I go back to the last restore point.

Answer (score 1):

Quick actions and other intellisense functions were not working for me.  When I started visual studio, the Solution Explorer pane was defaulting to Folder View, rather than Solution View[image: Solution vs Folder view]

Setting it back restored the proper functionality.
Visual Studio had defaulted to starting in this mode.  To start Visual Studio in Solution mode, go to Options/Projects and Solutions/General and ensure that `Track Active Item in Solution Explorer` is checked.

Comment: I encountered the same confusion, but I guess it is in VS2015, not VS2017. I fetched my code from VisualStudioOnline on a new PC with only VS2017. I got also that folder view. I didn't realize it's not the normal solution view and many things didn't work. Like I could not set a startup project or debug. It took me a day or two until I realised it's easy, just tell in the Solution Explorer, which solution it should use.

Comment: The first line in my comment above should be: I encountered the same confusion, but I guess it is in VS2017, not VS2015.