# Visual Studio 2015 quick action helpers have disappeared

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Until very recently, my copy of Visual Studio 2015 Professional provided a [very useful set of features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn872466.aspx), in particular...

- changing the name of a property/method would give a light-bulb icon and the ability to update all instances of those properties/methods
- using an unreferenced class/namespace would give a light-bulb icon and the ability to quickly add a `using`/`Imports`, along with multiple other options

Here is an example of the 2nd of the above... the light-bulb used to appear just to the left of the popup message.

[image]

I cannot find any obvious option that would turn this off.

The issue is happening in both C# and VB.Net projects

I recently had an issue with CodeLens, the solution I found told me to remove the `%TEMP%\ALM` directory.  This fixed the CodeLens, but I'm wondering if it could have effected the light-bulb helpers.

Does anybody know how to get the light-bulb helpers to return?

Comment: Can you select a variable name and then press F2 to see you can change or not?

Comment: @Nikhil - I have F2 mapped to bookmarks... what function should F2 perform?

Comment: it will do Rename

Comment: @Nikhil - I wasn't aware there was a rename function in VisualStudio, I presumed you just changed the name of the variable without needing something that initiated that action.  Although you've sent me down a route that could explain the situation, I've just had a VS error popup regarding missing CodeAnalysis assembly... am investigating now

Comment: Looks like it's "by design" as I haven't installed Update 3... maybe M$'s way of forcing you to get the latest... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42484325/visual-studio-2015-quick-actions-no-longer-working-error-could-not-load-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating to VS2015 Update 3 the light-bulb helpers have returned

Comment: Funny, updating to Update 3 is what caused the "using" option to disappear for me. Now when I want to quickly add a namespace, it ONLY gives me the option to add it inline and not at the top of my file.