# Visual studio refactor quick actions and refactoring error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring

I have this kind of error in visual studio

```
could not load file or assembly "Microsoft.Code.Analysis, Version=1.3.1.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies"
```

what can I do?

[image: refactor quick actions and refactoring error img1]
[image: refactor quick actions and refactoring error img2]

Comment: Do you have reference on it at your References in Solution Explorer?

Comment: possible duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536506/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-codeanalysis-version-1-3-1-0-cultu/42536507#42536507

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, version= 1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependenc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536506/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-codeanalysis-version-1-3-1-0-cultu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your comments,

I have done through;

Basically, in the Visual Studio menu select:

Tools-> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Console

In the console that appears at the bottom of Visual Studio run this command:

**Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform**

after installing the package, there are no problems about the issue