# Namespaces' suggestion doesn't work - Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

i want to import a class in another class with the "using" keyword to have something like this :

`using System.Windows;`

Normally, i put my mouse over the red line where the problem is and got this :
[I only have to click on "using System.Windows;" it and it's ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0C0gQ.png)

But now i only get this :[There's no "Using" suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuU8H.png) and if i press Ctrl + Maj + ; or Alt + Maj + F10 i get a popUp with this message :

> Can't load the file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=1.3.1.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

I've got friends who have the same problem..

Does anyone knows how to save me ?

Comment: You need to add the dll to your 'References' in the project.

Comment: did you manually add the assembly / dll to the project reference as well as the using..?

Comment: no i didn't ... but i'll try to add the dll to the references ! thanks guys

Comment: I added it in th references but it's in version 1.2.0.0 so i'll try to update it.

Comment: Also, if you want this to show up for your own classes, it will not till you build the project at least once after adding a new class for that class to show up in the namespace recommendations.

Comment: Have also a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536506/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-codeanalysis-version-1-3-1-0-cultu) SO question.