# Deploy .NET Console App on a different PC

Tags: c#, .net

I built two quick programs today.  The one I'm showing here is just a quick program that will change the date of a virtual machine to a specific date.  I've tested it and deployed it, but to no avail I cannot get it working on another machine.  I've double checked my work by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli) documentation.  Both PC's are running .NET 4.7.  I'm not sure what the problem is.  Any help is appreciated!

**The error:**

> Error: assembly specified in the dependencies manifest was not found -- package:  'microsoft.codeanalysis.common', version: '1.3.0', path: 'lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll'

**Project.cs**

```
using System; 
using System.IO; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
using System.Windows;

namespace vmRedundancy {

class Program {

    public struct SYSTEMTIME {
        public ushort wYear, wMonth, wDayOfWeek, wDay,
        wHour, wMinute, wSecond, wMilliseconds;
    }
    /// <param name="lpSystemTime">[out]</param>
    [DllImport ("kernel32.dll")]
    public extern static void GetSystemTime (ref SYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime);
    /// <param name="lpSystemTime">[in]</param>
    [DllImport ("kernel32.dll")]
    public extern static uint SetSystemTime (ref SYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime);

    static void Main (string[] args) {
        SYSTEMTIME st = new SYSTEMTIME();
        GetSystemTime(ref st);
        Console.WriteLine("The date was: " + st.wMonth + @"\" + st.wDay + @"\" + st.wYear); 
        st.wDay = 1;
        st.wMonth = 6;
        st.wYear = 2017;
        SetSystemTime(ref st);
        Console.WriteLine("The date is: " + st.wMonth + @"\" + st.wDay + @"\" + st.wYear); 
        //Console.WriteLine("The day of the week is: " + st.wDayOfWeek); 4
        Console.WriteLine("The time is: " + (st.wHour - 4) + ":" + st.wMinute + ":" + st.wSecond + " " + st.wMilliseconds + "ms"); 
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**ChangeDateTime.json**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win7-x64;win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

**The Publish: **

```
dotnet publish -r win7-x64
```

**dotnet --info (deployment)**

> .NET Command Line Tools (1.0.4)
>
> Product Information:
>     Version:            1.0.4
>     Commit SHA-1 hash: af1e6684fd
>
> Runtime Environment:
>    OS Name:     Windows
>    OS Version:  10.0.15063
>    OS Platform: Windows
>    RID:         win10-x64
>    Base Path:  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4

**dotnet --info (client)**

> .NET Command Line Tools (1.0.4)
>
> Product Information:
>    Version:            1.0.4
>    Commit SHA-1 hash: af1e6684fd
>
> Runtime Environment:
>    OS Name:     Windows
>    OS Version:  6.1.7601
>    OS Platform: Windows
>    RID:         win7-x64
>    Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4

Comment: According to the error, you're not including all the DLLs required by the binary.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536506/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-codeanalysis-version-1-3-1-0-cultu

Comment: @Juan this applies to Visual Studio IDE.  I'm building and publishing with the dotnet console compiler.

Comment: I understand that, but the issue is still the same. You are missing a library (as illustrated in the link) so I was hoping that could help you figure out why it's missing.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work by downloading and installing the .NET 4.7 SDK and changing everything to suit.  Seems weird that "core" compiled items don't work across different platforms.  I am sure I am misunderstanding something; I just don't know what!

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <TargetFramework>net47</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```