# Visual Studio: How to disable Code Analysis?

Tags: visual-studio, code-analysis

I'm building a Win32 DLL project (pure C) on MSVC 14 and getting some unrelated error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets(219,5): error : The source file for this compilation can be found at: "C:\Windows\TEMP\3020bf46-df05-4e6e-a019-3e0bb0f5627c.txt"
```

As far as I know, the stupid IDE tries to run some enforced services of MS on my code, (which I didn't ask for). I just disabled Code Analysis on project properties page, thou it had no effect.

Comment: Maybe try updating the nuget package per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42560044/2343739

Answer (score 0):

you can either add SuppressMessageAttribute to your source code or to GlobalSuppressions.cs file, these two actions can be invoked when you right click on the specific error/warning message under the error list tab.